# c# property with private setter: why do new [..class..] .. { private property initializer = ... } work?

Tags: c#, setter, initializer

I have this example code:

```
static class Program
{
    var x = new TestClass { TestList = { "Peter", "Paul" } };

    // x.TestList is loaded with 3 string elements: "Hi there", "Peter", "Paul"
}

public class TestClass
{
    public List<string> TestList {get; private set;}

    public TestClass() 
    {
        TestList = new List<string>() { "Hi there" };
    }
}
```

When I execute this code, `x.TestList` is loaded with 3 string elements: `"Hi there", "Peter", "Paul"`

### Questions

1. Why does C# allow this kind of initialization? I have a private setter on `TestList`, so why is it allowed?
2. Why is the resulting `x` list comprised of 3 elements, which are the union of the initialization code executed on the parameterless constructor and on the class initializer used when a new `TestClass` object is created? Why not 1 or 2 objects contained in the list instead?

**3. [MOST IMPORTANT]: How can I prevent this kind of behavior so as to prevent code injection pe. on string properties?**

Thanks.

Comment: Because it is not calling the setter. It calling the public Add method on the list which you have exposed. Use `IReadOnlyList<T>` or some other read-only interface to prevent clients from changing the list if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks Servy and Mike z for the info. I wasn't aware of the IEnumerable.Add(..) being invoked upon initializing IEnumerable collections.The collection reference cannot be altered (as using a new List<T> from the calling client code) because of the private setter, and items can effectively be added to the list via List.Add(..) and by the object initializer.